# bounds on a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It may look that this question is trivial, but:

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ a sequence s.t. $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \ \ a_n<\frac {1}{n}$. Prove/Disprove : there is $c > 1$ s.t. $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \ \ a_n<\frac {1}{n^c}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find a sequence for which there is no such $c$.

Take $\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}<a_n<\frac{1}{n}$.

Now given any $c>1$ we can find $N$ such that $c>1+\frac{1}{N}$, so $a_N>\frac{1}{n^c}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{2n}$. We have $\frac{1}{n^c}=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for all $c > 1$. This means that for any positive $\epsilon$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that:
$$n > N \implies \frac{1}{n^c} \leq \epsilon \frac{1}{n}$$
Now, choose $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. We now have:
$$n > N \implies \frac{1}{n^c} \leq \frac{1}{2n}$$
Thus, there is no $c > 1$ such that $\frac{1}{n^c} > \frac{1}{2n}$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ because there is always an $n$ big enough so that this becomes not true, meaning $a_n=\frac{1}{2n}$ is our counterexample to your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_ {n}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n!}$ then $a_{n}<\frac{1}{n},\forall n$,

but $\forall c>1$ $a_{n}<\frac{1}{n^{c}}$ means $ 1<\frac{1}{n^{c-1}}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ and this is false since the RHS tends to $0$, when $n$ goes to infinity.